# Selecting an option from an optgroup with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I would like to choose a value from this optgroup which should then give me a dropdown of links.

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <select id="q" multiple="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
    <option></option>
    <option class="q-all-text" value="al:all">Search all text</option>

    <optgroup label="Business Type">
        <option value="bt:Buyer">Buyer</option>
        <option value="bt:Farmer/Rancher">Farmer/Rancher</option>
        <option value="bt:Farmers Market">Farmers Market</option>
        <option value="bt:Fishery">Fishery</option>
        <option value="bt:Food Bank">Food Bank</option>
    </optgroup>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://foodmarketmaker.com/main/mmsearch")
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

select  = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-hidden- accessible"))
select.select_by_value("bt:Farmer/Rancher")
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
print(links)
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

I either get an exception that the element does not exist, or when I access by index, i get an ElementNotVisibleException due to the aria-hidden attribute being true. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Either you can simulate some action like hovering or clicking somewhere which makes your elements visible and then select the element . If it get visible in some time then use explicit wait. or you intend to select that element any how then use JavaScript executor to change that aria-hidden to false and select the same

Answer (score 1):

`select` is not the node that you need to handle as it's not visible.

Try below code to get required output:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = web.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://foodmarketmaker.com/main/mmsearch")
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//section[@id="search-right"]//input[@placeholder="start typing to search"]'))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[.="Bass"]'))).click()

links = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//section[@id="search-results"]//a[.//*[name()="svg"]]')))

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

P.S. You need to replace text value of `li` node in `'//li[.="Bass"]'` XPath with required option

Comment: I am trying to scroll through the results so that I can load all of the links, however it won't scroll. Is there a specific way of scrolling in an iframe? I tried using execute script and scrolling to bottom of page but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to print all the options you have to induce *WebDriverWait* to switch to the desired frame, then click on the *Search Box* for the *options* to be visible as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://foodmarketmaker.com/main/mmsearch")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://search.foodmarketmaker.com']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='searchbar']//input[@class='select2-search__field' and @placeholder='start typing to search']"))).click()
  links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='select2-results__option' and @aria-label='Business Type']/strong//following::ul[1]//li")
  for link in links:
      print(link.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  Buyer
  Buyer: Baked Goods
  Buyer: Beverages
  Buyer: Dairy
  Buyer: Fish &amp; Seafood
  Buyer: Fruit &amp; Nuts
  Buyer: Grains &amp; OilSeed
  Buyer: Herbs
  Buyer: Meat &amp; Poultry
  Buyer: Miscellaneous
  Buyer: Specialty Products
  Buyer: Sugar/Confectionary &amp; Snacks
  Buyer: Vegetables
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Cafeteria &amp; Buffet
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Caterer
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Drinking Place
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Food Service Contractor
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Mobile Food Service
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Restaurant
  Eating &amp; Drinking Place: Snack &amp; Nonalcoholic Beverage Bar
  Farmer/Rancher
  Farmer/Rancher: Dairy
  Farmer/Rancher: Forage
  Farmer/Rancher: Fruits &amp; Nuts
  Farmer/Rancher: Grains
  Farmer/Rancher: Herbs
  Farmer/Rancher: Livestock Production (Beef Cattle)
  Farmer/Rancher: Meat &amp; Poultry
  Farmer/Rancher: Specialty Products
  Farmer/Rancher: Vegetables
  Farmers Market
  Fishery
  Fishery: Fish/Shellfish/Seafood
  Food Bank
  Food Bank: Food Bank
  Food Hub
  Food Retailer
  Food Retailer: Baked Goods Store
  Food Retailer: Beer, Wine &amp; Liquor Store
  Food Retailer: Candy, Nut &amp; Confectionery
  Food Retailer: Fish Market
  Food Retailer: Fruit &amp; Vegetable Market
  Food Retailer: Grocery/Convenience Store
  Food Retailer: Health Supplement Store
  Food Retailer: Meat &amp; Poultry Market
  Food Retailer: Other Direct Selling Establishments
  Food Retailer: Other Specialty Food Store
  General Member
  Processor/Packing Shed
  Processor/Packing Shed: Animal Food Manufacturing
  Processor/Packing Shed: Bakery Products
  Processor/Packing Shed: Beverages
  Processor/Packing Shed: Dairy Products
  Processor/Packing Shed: Fish/Shellfish/Seafood Products
  Processor/Packing Shed: Fruit &amp; Vegetable Products
  Processor/Packing Shed: Grain &amp; Oilseed Milling
  Processor/Packing Shed: Meat &amp; Poultry Products
  Processor/Packing Shed: Miscellaneous
  Processor/Packing Shed: Packing Shed
  Processor/Packing Shed: Sugar and Confectionery Products
  Tourism
  Tourism: Agritourism
  Tourism: Fishing Charter
  Tourism: Hunting
  Wholesaler
  Wholesaler: Beer, Wine &amp; Alcoholic Beverages
  Wholesaler: Confectionery &amp; Snacks
  Wholesaler: Dairy Products
  Wholesaler: Farm Products
  Wholesaler: Fish/Shellfish/Seafood
  Wholesaler: Fruit &amp; Vegetable
  Wholesaler: General Grocery
  Wholesaler: Meat &amp; Poultry
  Wholesaler: Other Grocery
  Wholesaler: Packaged Frozen Food
  Winery
  Winery: Blends or Generic Wine
  Winery: Fortified Wine
  Winery: Fruit Wine
  Winery: Other Wine Products
  Winery: Red Wine
  Winery: Sparkling Wine
  Winery: White Wine
  ```